# Power analysis of mixed model using bootstrapping in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, bootstrap

I am trying to make power analysis using bootstrap on the following set of data :

```
     ID    score   position  rate  inclus  Condition  level 
  Sujet10  score2     Pos7    10      1         7      2  
  Sujet10  score2     Pos4    10      1         7      2  
  Sujet10  score2     Pos6    10      1         7      2  
  Sujet10  score2     Pos2    10      1         7      2  
  Sujet10  score2     Pos5    10      1         7      2  
  Sujet10  score1     Pos1    10      1         7      2
```

The data gives, for 14 participants, the rate of each element in a list of 7 elements according to its position in the list, each element being scored two times.

I want to calculate power analysis on the p value of the factor "position" on the rate in the following mixed model :

```
mixed(rate ~ level*position*score + (1|Sujet), data=subset(my_data, 
      inclus==1),check_contrasts=FALSE)

                 Effect     df      F   p.value
1                level  1, 12    1.81     .34
2              position 6, 156   1.78     .01
3                 score 1, 156   0.21     .69
4       level:variable  6, 156   1.48     .19
5          level:score  1, 156   0.61     .67
6        level:score    6, 156   0.12     .99
7 level:position:score  6, 156   0.20     .57
```

I am only interested in the p-value of the factor "position" effect for the power analysis.

I have tried this function (with only 10 iterations to begin):

```
boot_s <- function(formula, data, indices) {                                                                                                                                                               
  d <- data[indices,]                                                                                                                                                       
  mixy <- mixed(formula, data=d)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  coef(summixy)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}     

power_results <- boot(data=my_data, statistic=boot_s, R=10, 
                      formula=rate~level*position*score + (1|Sujet))
```

But I don't know how to interpret the output of the function `power_results` :

```
           original        bias     std. error
t1*    9.069143e+00 -9.755929e-02 6.805105e-01
t2*   -1.870000e-01  1.986001e-02 1.066356e-01
t3*   -1.335143e+00  6.576995e-01 5.708863e-01
t4*   -1.425143e+00 -1.255020e+00 2.513071e+00
...
t140*  8.407994e-01 -2.332730e-01 3.770720e-01
```

I have two questions :

1. What do all these t* refer to and how to find specifically the effect for the factor "position" in this output ?
2. How can I select participants with specific levels of my factors for the power analysis ?